# how to return a json response of validation in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5.4

**Validation code**

```
 $this->validate($request, [
            'email'=> 'required|email|unique:users',
            'email'=> 'required|max:120',
            'password' => 'required|min:4'
            ]);
```

*how can i return the errors of validation if they exist as a json response?*

Comment: This should work, what are you trying to do? How do you make the request, in a browser or via postman?

Answer (score 1):

Using `$this->validate` on the controller action automates the whole process significantly. If the validation fails, it automatically redirects to the previous page, while a list of errors should be available in `$errors` variable in your view.

If you want to have a control over the process you can do it that way:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
  return $validator->errors();
}

// Validation successful
```

Please see https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation for more information.